# Sending geo-spoofing from ADB doesn't change the location on Tinder

Tags: android, sdk, geolocation, location, adb

I connected my non-jailbroken android 13 device to my laptop (enabled mock location, usb debugging)

I want to spoof my Tinder's location so I ran these two `adb` commands.

But it won't change tinder's applicative location.

How can I achieve this?

```
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb -s 2C051FDH3002LA shell appops set com.google.android.gms android:mock_location allow

~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb -s 2C051FDH3002LA shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.GEO_LOCATION --es "lat" "38.6979" --es "long" "-9.2064" --ei "error" "10"
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.GEO_LOCATION flg=0x400000 (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

Comment: Setting a permission allows an app to use a feature, but doesn't force it to use the feature.  I highly doubt Tinder's release version uses mock location in its code.

Comment: @Gabe how would you send geo-spoofing to Tinder from the laptop? because VPN + fakeGPS apps are not affecting tinder.

Comment: I mean you could go to extreme lengths (build your own version of AOSP with a modified version of the location API that does it).   It's probably easier to just download the apk and install it on an emulator, where you can fake out the location.  But generally they don't make something like that easy to do-  if you're debugging your own code there's better ways (mock locations), if you're not then they really don't want you to do that at all.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks! I would love to do it somehow easily, I saw desktop applications that promise to do this with tinder. So I guess there is a way to control remotely. My commands are in the right direction?